# view-scroll-half-page-forward messes up scrolling

Tags: scrolling, view-mode

I have the following in my config

```
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position 1)
;;scroll window up/down by one line



(global-set-key (kbd "s-n") (kbd "C-u 1 C-v"))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-p") (kbd "C-u 1 M-v"))

(global-set-key "\C-v"   'View-scroll-half-page-forward)
(global-set-key "\M-v"   'View-scroll-half-page-backward)
```

and using C-v and M-v works as expected. But after using s-n or s-p, invoking C-v and M-v just behaves as if I use s-n and s-p again, namely scrolling the buffer up/down one line at a time.

It seems that this overwrites the half-page scrolling somehow and the only thing that helps to reset the behaviour to default, is to close and reopen the respective buffer. Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?